# Finding all the embeddings from $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ into $\mathbb{C}$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

From $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4 , $ I know that there are are $4$ embeddings {$\sigma_1 ,\sigma_2,\sigma_3,\sigma_4$} .

Furthermore, each element in $K$ can be written as $$ a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6} \ \ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$$

So first I have the identity $$\sigma_1(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6} $$

Then I have to consider $$ \sigma_2(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})$$

I  know that I have to take the conjugate of some terms , here for $\sqrt{2}$
and $\sqrt{3} $ , but I do not really understand why I have to consider these roots .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the extension is generated by $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$, so the embedding is defined (generated) by the images of these two numbers.

The image of $\sqrt 2$ has to satisfy $x^2-2=0$ and the image of $\sqrt 3$ has to satisfy $x^2-3=0$ (these being the minimal polynomials of the two roots over $\mathbb Q$).

These basic facts define the options for embeddings, which you should be able to identify.

Comment: Then you can say that $\sigma_2(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6})=a-b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}-d\sqrt{6}$ ?

Comment: @AnabolicHorse If you change the sign of $\sqrt 2$ but not $\sqrt 3 $ you also change the sign of $\sqrt 6=\sqrt 2\times \sqrt 3$

Comment: Can you say that $\sigma_2(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sigma_2(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}$ . So you have $\sigma_2(\sqrt{2})\sigma_2(\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{6}$ ?

Comment: @AnabolicHorse That's the way to do it

Comment: Does the order of the embeddings play a role ?

Comment: For example if you want to calculate the discriminant .